# Quick search filter URL Customize

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

http://127.0.0.1/CavendishOnline/catalogsearch/result/?q=Sift+Stone+Graphite I want to remove Plus mark in end of the URL String How to do this in Magento 2.3 community Version

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that the query text includes basically spaces and you would like to remove the spaces between the words in the query text.

You could create an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index` event:

in your module, in `etc/frontend/events.xml` file, add:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index">
        <observer name="change_query_text" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeQueryText"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

in your observer class `Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeQueryText.php`, you can change this:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

/**
 * Class ChangeQueryText
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer
 */
class ChangeQueryText implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $queryString = trim($this->request->getQuery('q'));
        $newQuery = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $queryString);
        $this->request->setParam('q', $newQuery);
    }
}
```